# Adjust height between two span elements

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I am trying to adjust vertical space between two span elements inside a div. I am trying to achieve half of what I am getting from `<br/>`.

`line-height` , `vertical-align` or `margin-top`. 
None of it worked for me. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/himanshuy/xnYPH/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<span>` elements are inline. You can't put block-level elements like `<p`> inside of inline elements.

Use `<div>`s instead of `<span>`s and your CSS will work just fine:

```
<div class="signupEmailBox">
    <div class="tag"><p>test data goes here</p></div>
    <div class="smallTextEmail">
                    <p>blah blah blah</p>
                    <p>some text goes here...</p>
                    <p>here some more text data</p>
                    <p>some more text</p>
    </div>
</div>
​
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property named [display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) affecting the application of margin among others. The value of this property defaults to `inline` for span elements. Therefore there is no margin applied.

Either use a element with another default value like a div box or change the value of the display property of your span elements. I suggest using `inline-block` because this preserves the text flow capabilities of the span element.

```
span
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I would rather changed the selector do something less general, say `.class span`.